# "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow" Is there an auto-deletion?

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits

##### Core considerations are at the bottom if you're short on time.

---

Is there any sort of auto-deletion of suggested edits after a certain amount of time? It gets pretty annoying to have to wait for moderators to go around reviewing until you can finally suggest edits again, and this leads to plenty of posts never getting edits since, by the time you can edit again, you're not going to still have all the tabs open that needed suggested edits, let alone expect the reviewers to be able to keep up with them as well.

##### *Edit:*

@OlegValteriswithUkraine has answered that there is no auto-deletion of suggested edits after a certain period. I now would like to clarify that I would like to discuss *any* possible solution to the above-mentioned problem, such as the ability to delete the suggested edits in your own queue or whatever anyone can think of. Finally, I also wanted to express that **my annoyance is not at the reviewers** that I wait on, but **the fact that *I have to wait* for them**. And so, I would like to figure out a better way than how it currently is. Being able to delete our own edit if we have deemed it minutiae is probably the best so far to root out all the small distractions the reviewers come across, but whatever you can think of would be appreciated.

##### *Edit:*

To put it in perspective, as I put it in a responding comment below, ***there is a hole in the ship—no matter how small—to be filled*** (figuratively speaking). Yes, the reviewers are doing *fantastic* and that's wonderful, but there are still days where there are just "too many pending edits" for hours, and all would-be-attempted edits are lost—good or bad. Can the ratio of reviewers to general users be maintained? Yeah, mostly.  But perhaps there's some way to give people a faster opportunity to become editors.

#### Main Point:

Because reputation is gained based on your technical knowledge, an obvious fact faces us:

**You don't need to be an expert in all those technical things to be an expert in English, formatting, better communicating, etc. (although a little of the former is still good on this site)**.

There must be a more efficient (yet rigorous and prudent) way to become an editor than there currently is.

##### Specific Ideas (I'll add to this list):

- Give the opportunity to request the ability to review post edits starting at, say, 100–300 reputation, but with extra measures.

###### Extra:

This relevant question was asked recently that brought up good points as well: [Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424406/allow-2000-rep-users-to-bypass-the-queue-limit-when-suggesting-edits-in-review)

Comment: Are you asking for this to be implemented (feature-request) or asking if it already exists (support)?

Comment: Both; I am asking if it is already a thing, and if it isn't, should it be?

Comment: I dont think any suggested edits are in the queue for more than 2 weeks (on the high end). In my experience, most get approved or rejected within 4 days. And the autodelete will only work in the short term since the queue would get clogged with new edits

Comment: You appear to be underestimating the volume of suggested edits which are made on Stack Overflow. It's not that there are a bunch of old edits jamming up the queue. It's just that there are substantially more suggested edits made, or attempted, than the proportionate number of reviews performed to approve/reject the suggested edits. The *vast* majority are reviewed way, *way*, **way** before 3 months expire. You should be aware of this just from your own history of suggested edits, all of which have been handled, except the most recent one.

Comment: FYI, what users who volunteer their time for free *don't* like is other users *demanding* of them to do even more work than they already do. Your request comes off as *at least* "pretty annoying" and may even cross over into outright "rude".

Comment: One of the problems is that too many people are doing a lot of very insignificant edits to otherwise poor posts. On its own correcting every typo you see is not bad, but it is not the most appropriate thing to do when you don't have enough reputation to make an edit outside the queue. Choose posts you edit wisely.

Comment: @VLAZ, I was clearly **not** demanding more of them, but rather pointing out that what they deal with is **too much** for them, and that we need to find a way to **make it easier** on them. Literally the opposite of what you're saying. The last part I put even before the edit made that clear.

Comment: @RobertBradley the text you had in the title "Please go review them." did give off the wrong impression.

Comment: @VLAZ, Yes, that was a side note , and I removed it because apparently people read too much into that, but the overall question and what I put at the end should have made it clear if people read carefully and didn't jump to things.

Comment: @VLAZ, I didn't put "it's pretty annoying waiting for moderators" or "it's pretty annoying to wait for moderators", I put "it's pretty annoying to **have to** wait for moderators", I put careful attention into what I say, I just wish people would notice, because I try my best to avoid confusion like this. That was in the original post by the way.

Comment: Real people will check millions of our suggestions. Maybe they even spend more time to checking them than time we edited the post. So, be patient :)

Comment: Mine's still saying I have too many pending when I only have 1 pending/open.

Comment: @tornadoradon, as I have put excessively clearly, I am **not annoyed at the reviewers**, but pointing out that it may be **too much to leave on them**, because some days there is a long gap (most of the day) of "too many pending edits", and all would-be-attempted edits at this time are lost—good or bad. I'm just pointing out that there is a hole in the ship—no matter how small—to be filled (figuratively speaking).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Be Patient**

If you get annoyed by having to wait for a while to have your suggested edits handled, you *seriously* underestimate the sheer size of Stack Overflow. And even at that size, we are actually doing pretty well in terms of going through review queues (need I mention that reviewers are unpaid volunteers who take time off to handle those edits you submit?) — here is a graph comparing the total number of suggested edits to the time it took to handle them ([SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1674807/suggested-edits-by-time-it-took-to-handle-them)):

[image: graph of the number of handled suggested edits to the number of days it took to handle showing most edits being handled on the first day, a non-insignificant chunk on the second day, and only a tiny fraction taking more than 2 days up to about 3 years]

As you can probably see, pretty much *every* suggested edit on Stack Overflow is handled within the first few days with some exceptions (the most important one being tag wiki/excerpt edits — they can take months to be approved due to the lack of eligible reviewers with an interest in tags, as well as poor discoverability of such tasks).

Take a close look at the magnitude of numbers in that graph too: we are talking about *millions* of items.

> this leads to plenty of posts never getting edits

As you probably surmised from the above as well, there is no shortage of edits suggested for posts. In fact, we have too many of them even with the current limitations (5 pending edits per user, 500 items cap for pending edits in the queue).

> Is there any sort of auto-deletion of suggested edits after three months or so?

No, there isn't. And we are better off for it: what makes newer suggestions better than the old ones? That they are more recent? This certainly says nothing about their quality. So why would those items be pushed out of the queue in favor of some new suggestion that might (and, speaking from experience as an active reviewer on Stack Overflow, most of the time *is*) be utter crap?

Comment: I think you really misunderstood my post, the annoyance was not at the reviewers, and clearly did not underestimate the size of the site, in fact, I was addressing that the large size is too much on the reviewers. The auto-delete after 3 months is just 1 idea, it could be the ability to delete our own suggested edits. Mainly my worry is, I only suggest edits on new posts, and if I see an error in a post made several years ago, I don't make a suggested edit, because it is just going to sit in my queue for years since there is no way that reviewers can check all posts decade-old posts for edits.

Comment: I believe I understood the post - my central point, backed by public data, is that, on average, most edits are handled in under a day or two at most, so when some edits fall through the cracks, the only solution is to just be patient, reviewers will get to it in time. That said, you are not incorrect in saying that there are too many edits for reviewers to handle - unfortunately, we are clogged with very minor, useless, or downright harmful edits - all of which steal the spotlight from other, more significant edits. That is a big issue indeed. The idea to retract suggested edits has been [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] brought up before, and, yeah, it is possible that it might at least *somewhat* mitigate the problem (at least in terms of submitting new edits if one decides to allocate their 5 pending edits quota elsewhere). Unfortunately, if done properly (it's a complex feature to build because one needs to account for items already being reviewed at the time of retraction, etc), it'll require quite a lot of dev time, and SE the company isn't exactly known for assigning resources to community feature requests these past years.

Comment: Believe me, I understand the frustration about the limit, but I just don't see how allowing items to expire would help with that. We need to treat the problem by solving its root cause, which is two-fold: (1) an incredibly shitty experience for reviewers (grind, lack of guidance, bad UI *and* UX), leading to many either not bothering or burning out; (2) a neverending stream of extremely minor edits or edits that fail to follow editing guidelines (onboarding problem, lack of documentation, etc). Solving these problems will, by extension, solve the problem of having to sometimes wait for a while

Comment: @RobertBradley your point about ancient edits is wrong. It doesn’t matter how old the post is, an edit is an edit. It is in the queue just like a recent post. They all get handled in days.