# Edit stuck in limbo - what do I do?

Tags: discussion, review, edits

I edited my question ([How do I resolve Wix form 'Couldn't submit due to temporary issue' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75773980/how-do-i-resolve-wix-form-could-submit-due-to-temporary-issue-error)) to reverse changes someone had made (and seemed unhelpful).

The review of my edit has been pending for two days.

This is longer than I’m used to, and inconsistent with at the all-of-site review rate (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) with some reasonable assumptions.

Is my question edit stuck, and if so, what do I do about it? The longer the edit takes to process the sooner it will slip from the top of the new questions and less likely it will seen by someone who might be able to answer it.

Any counsel welcome. My first meta post I think so I hope it’s not too misguided.

As the commenters point out, I apparently didn’t edit my question from the account I posted it (my mistake) to complicate things.

Comment: Wait - if its *your* question - why is this account, and the account that asked the question different? You would have been able to rollback an edit on your own posts on the same account.

Comment: If that's your question, then you didn't edit it with the account you posted it. Edits on your own posts do not need approvals normally.

Comment: You guys are right. I didnt realise I’d edited it with a different account, my apologies. Regardless, what can I expect regarding edit processing times? I guess it doesnt matter so much since I can just rollback the edit drom the questioning posting account.

Comment: Not much can be done about the SO edit queue length on our side. But yeah, depending in your reasons for socks - the solution is really to keep track of which accounts you are on better,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't the edit queue—it's that you've got alternate accounts and didn't really keep track of which account you were using. In general, you need to be careful about things like this—since practically, you shouldn't be interacting with your 'own' posts with different accounts where reputation is involved. A rollback from the 'right' account is fine, and it's a good thing you didn't approve the edit from your alternate accounts.

The edit queue on Stack Overflow is something that's broadly discussed on their meta. It gets full and doesn't get cleared out as quickly as people would like, but it's a hard problem to solve.

Comment: Unless there's a good reason for having two accounts, they should be [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) by the user.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks. As in my answer, which apparently I was writing as you were writing yours, I asked the general q of wait times regardless. But won’t pursue it further. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Will look into that Laurel.

Answer (score 1):

Journeyman and Vlaz rightly pointed out that I submitted the edit from a different account to the one I posted the question (which was unintentional).

That offers a solution to my problem yet perhaps leaves open the question as to why an edit from any account should take multiple days.

I dont know typical wait times so I will leave that to someone else to ask if they are so inclined and judge it to have merit.

Thanks all, and apologies.

Comment: "*yet perhaps leaves open the question as to why an edit from any account should take multiple days.*" 1. The edit queue on SO is almost full. Which is its constant state. The maximum review items are 500 and that's usually close to the number of reviews in the queue. 2. Edits that correct spelling and grammar are easier to review. Do the changes just improve the post? Done. Your edit was to add a tag which require more work for reviewers. Reading and understanding the question, as well as the tag usage guidance. Some reviewers might have skipped the review for that.

Comment: "*I dont know typical wait times*" You can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1674807/suggested-edits-by-time-it-took-to-handle-them) from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383976). Although it omits some information. In particular, suggested edits on tags typically take a lot longer to be actioned than post edits. Also, site activity is lower over weekends, so suggested edits on Friday/Saturday may take a bit longer. Since you had already waited two days *on Monday*, your suggested edit was one of those.

Comment: Interesting, thanks VLAZ. Assuming that data is current, at least you can say there was no website wide issue in responding to edit requests (relative to the similar looking static chart in the post). As you say, perhaps the combo of edit complexity and diminished reviewer activity. Stack on